# How to delete an event in vtiger using REST APIs and where to get WEBSERVICE_ID from?

Tags: php, rest, web, vtiger

I want to delete an event in Vtiger Calendar using REST APIs. I'm trying the following:

```
POST /webservice.php HTTP/1.1
operation=delete
sessionName=sessionId    // Obtained through Login Operation
id=<WEBSERVICE_ID>
```

but I don't know what WEBSERVICE_ID is and where to find it.

When I create an event using REST-API it returns an array with the following data:

```
{"subject":"Follow up Test","assigned_user_id":"49x1","date_start":"2016-06-17","time_start":"09:00:00","time_end":"18:00:00","due_date":"2016-06-17","recurringtype":"","parent_id":"","contact_id":"","taskstatus":"","eventstatus":"Planned","taskpriority":"High","sendnotification":"0","createdtime":"2016-06-23 11:18:20","modifiedtime":"2016-06-23 11:18:20","activitytype":"Event","visibility":"","duration_hours":"9","duration_minutes":"0","location":"","notime":"0","modifiedby":"49x1","created_user_id":"49x1","source":"WEBSERVICE","starred":"0","tags":"","reminder_time":"","description":"Test Description","id":"1x5748","label":"Follow up Test"}
```

There is an **id** in the array ("id":"1x5748"), but when I try to use the id as a WEBSERVICE_ID in the delete operation I'm getting the following error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Error: Id specified is incorrect'

Answer (score 2):

1. Run this query: `SELECT id, nameFROM vtiger_ws_entity`
   Whith this your  `objectTypeId` is a id for module
2. Get the record id
3. concatenate 1And2 for example: `EVENTS module='18' AND record id=61900`, then the **ID** that you need is: 18x61900;
4. I use this code for delete entity

   ```
   $params = array(
       //"id" => "35789",
       "id" => "18x61900",
   );
   $record = $client->doInvoke("delete", $params, "POST");
   ```